# "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement" when trying to CREATE VIEW

Tags: sql, ms-access

I keep getting the error message "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement" when I try to run the following CREATE VIEW statement in Access:

```sql
CREATE VIEW SeanWalshOrders (cNo, cName, street, city, county, discount)
AS
SELECT cNo, cName, street, city, county, discount
FROM orders
WHERE saleRepName = "Sean Walsh";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your CREATE VIEW statement will work if executed using an OLEDB connection, e.g., from an external application or via the `CurrentProject.Connection` object in Access VBA. However, Access does not accept CREATE VIEW statements when entered into the SQL pane of the Query Designer within Access itself (which uses a DAO connection, not OLEDB). In that context it is expecting a CREATE TABLE statement (as indicated by the error message.)

For more details see a related question here:

[Attempting CREATE VIEW in Access gives "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32770318/2144390)