# INNER JOIN on 3 tables. SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to make a query which prints out book title (in book table) and the author's name (in author table) but from a separate table that has all the book ID's of a certain sales rep. A picture of the tables in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4whVP.png

My code so far is

```
SELECT book.title, author.fName, author.surname
FROM author 
INNER JOIN book ON author.aID = book.authorID 
INNER JOIN SeanWalshOrders ON book.isbn = SeanWalshOrders.bookID;
```

Comment: What is the problem? that looks like a good approach.

Comment: and what is your excact Problem? Exception? No data?

maybe try to alias your different tables. Not sure if you can access the different tables by simple take their names and not an alias

Comment: if ms-access version is not upper than 2003 you need add ( , ) in JOIN part

Comment: Looks ok to me too. I wouldn't have a table called 'SeanWalshOrders', but rather two tables, one of orders (order id, book id, agent id) and one of agents (agent id, agent name). This is much more flexible than having a separate table for each sales rep.

Comment: It says syntax error and highlights Name on fName

Comment: @gibs. That is weird. it gives you error on `, author.fName , `?

Comment: @SQB Judging by the icon on the tab in the screenshot, [SeanWalshOrders] is a query, not a table. See related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19817894/2144390).

Comment: First of all, if you have one table of orders per sales rep, you're doing it wrong. Instead of tables SeanWalshOrders, JohnDoeOrders and so on, have a table salesRep which contains the name of all sales reps, just like author contains all authors.
Then create a table sales, which links a sale to a rep, by his or hers id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I try to run the query as posted in the question I get the error

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'author.aID = book.authorID INNER JOIN SeanWalshOrders ON book.isbn = SeanWalshOrders.bookI'.

When I re-construct that query using the Query Designer in Access it produces

```sql
SELECT book.title, author.fName, author.surname
FROM 
    (
        SeanWalshOrders 
        INNER JOIN 
        book 
            ON SeanWalshOrders.bookID = book.isbn
    ) 
    INNER JOIN 
    author 
        ON book.authorID = author.aID;
```

Access can be a bit fussy about parentheses in multiple JOINs.