# How can i introduce multiple conditions in LIKE operator for MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I would like to know, if there is any way, how to achieve something like this in access sql.

```
select * from my_table where column_name like ('ABC%', 'MOP%');
```

I tried use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1387797/1784053 but this seems not to work in Access.

Is there way on how to achieve anything like multiple like conditioning based on dynamic set of conditions? This means, that I cant use `OR` neither `UNION` because my set of conditions is dynamic.

Similar question: [How can i introduce multiple conditions in LIKE operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387612/how-can-i-introduce-multiple-conditions-in-like-operator)

Comment: How do you build the SQL statement? Where are the conditions coming from?

Comment: Basically I have something like this at the moment: 
`Select * from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.column1 like (select t2.column1 where t2.column2 > 50)`

Comment: @Kajiyama did you find the solution to this?

Comment: @Babar unfortunately not, we went with a totally different approach in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
select * 
from my_table 
where column_name like ('ABC%') or column_name like ('MOP%');
```

Comment: As mentioned in question. I am using dynamic set and therefore i cant use neither `OR` nor `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

Would using `IN` be enough?

i.e.

```
select * from my_table where column_name in ("ABC", "MOP");
```

You could also replace the `IN` clause with a select from another table.

Also you could use a VBA function:

```
select * from my_table where IsValidColumnName(column_name);
```

The IsValidColumnName would be a simple function that returns a bool if it matches whatever conditions you want.

To add the function, create a new module and then you can enter something like:

```
Public Function IsValidColumnName(columnName As String) As Boolean

If columnName Like "ABC*" Or columnName Like "MOP*" Then
    IsValidColumnName = True
Else
    IsValidColumnName = False
End If

End Function
```

Notice the Like statements changed, `LIKE` in VBA uses the DOS wildcards, you had SQL Server ones in your question.

Comment: Nope, this won't work because I am searching for substring not whole string value. Therefor `IN` won't return what i am looking for

Comment: then the VBA function approach looks like your best bet, as the function could do anything.

Comment: can you be more specific and provide some example please?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Function

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20))
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(   
  position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(8000)  
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int
SET @index = -1

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
  BEGIN 
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK 
      END 
    IF (@index > 1) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
      END 
    ELSE
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
    END
  RETURN
END
```

Query

```
select * from my_table inner join (select value from fn_split('ABC,MOP',','))
as split_table on my_table.column_name like '%'+split_table.value+'%';
```

Comment: This ends up with: `Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.`

Comment: first create a function and than execute the query

Comment: I mean Create function statement (i ran only create function statement) threw this error

Comment: how it is giving  Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement. because there is not a 'create table' statement in  my function

Comment: I assume it will have something to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19837233/1784053

Comment: sorry i dont know why my create function giving an error in your sql

Comment: probably because the SQL is for SQL Server and not Access SQL.